# How to fix a 'Next with no For' error sent in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm setting up an automated calendar that should draw a name from varName() when the corresponding date in varDate() appears in the calendar(Fday is the calendar date). I am receiving confusingly getting the "Next without For" error in the loop.

The aim is to have a dynamic array for name(varName) and date(varName) where the name can be drawn into a calendar day with the corresponding date. I have succeeded in drawing a name into a calendar according to the corresponding date using a static array however when I use dynamic arrays it is giving me problems.

```
stRow = Row with calendar date
stCol = Column with calendar date
nameRow = Row containing persons name (below calendar date)

    For i = LBound(varDate) To UBound(varDate)
      If Cells(stRow + 1, stCol) = Empty Then
       nameRow = stRow + 1
       If Fday = varDate(i) Then
        csheet.Cells(nameRow, stCol) = varName(i)
       End If
   Else
     nameRow = nameRow + 1  
     If Fday = varDate(i + 1) Then
       csheet.Cells(nameRow, stCol) = varName(i + 1)
     End If
    Next i
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should indent your code... that way you will avoid this error:

```
stRow = Row with calendar date
stCol = Column with calendar date
nameRow = Row containing persons name (below calendar date)

For i = LBound(varDate) To UBound(varDate)
    If Cells(stRow + 1, stCol) = Empty Then
        nameRow = stRow + 1
        If Fday = varDate(i) Then
            csheet.Cells(nameRow, stCol) = varName(i)
        End If
    Else
        nameRow = nameRow + 1
        If Fday = varDate(i + 1) Then
            csheet.Cells(nameRow, stCol) = varName(i + 1)
        End If 'you missed this one
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Damian, the error was resolved.

I am getting an error when I get to the 4th line of code (If Fday = varDate(i) Then) saying that the varDate(i) subscript is out of range. Any advice?

Dim varName() As Variant
Dim varDate() As Variant

varName = Range("K2", "K3")
varDate = Range("L2", "L3")

Comment: Debug your code and look for the value of `nameRow`& `stCol` on the code you given `stCol` is not initialized so it might be that.

Comment: The values for nameRow & stCol are correct and initialized.

Is the array defined correctly?

Comment: Now that I read it, no, you are giving the variant Ranges, not values, you need to give it values `varName = Array(Range("K2").Value, Range("K3").Value)` if your goal is to end up with values.

Comment: The goal was to insert a persons name under a date that corresponds with their own. The simple solution was to insert a column into the array.
e.g. varName (i, 2)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have this error, it means I'm actually missing an 'End If' somewhere. Excel thinks the Next statement is inside the IF block because it hasn't found an End If, but there's no For in that IF block!

So that's the reason you get the error.

Damian has spotted where the missing End If should go and put it back in. He's right that proper indention makes these errors very easy to spot.